# How to use functions in Ocaml Batteries?

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-batteries

I would like to use functions of [module `List` of Ocaml Batteries](http://batteries.forge.ocamlcore.org/doc.preview%3abatteries-alpha3/html/api/List.html). I have installed Batteries, and write code as follows:

```
open Extlib
...
Extlib.ExtList.List.remove ...
```

While compiling, it gives me an error `Error: Unbound module Extlib`. Does anyone know what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation, particularly the getting started section, here:

https://github.com/ocaml-batteries-team/batteries-included/wiki/

While Batteries uses some code from Extlib, they are separate projects.